# No ole db destination in ssis?

Tags: ssis

Trying to import to SQL Db from flatfile.. But [its throwing error..](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009672)  'Bulk-insert' failing with SQL Server Destination in SSIS. Googling led me to [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/09ae808e-bbd4-4bd0-9056-fffc9b413599/) . But I realized there is no 'Ole Db Destination' in my SSIS BIDS..! Am I missing something or..is it my VM 2008 Server 64bit and SQL Server 2008 R2?! :O

Now am using 'ADO.Net' Destination which is so slow for my purpose.. Did anyone else face the same prob..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rightclick the toolbox area and select "Choose Items" - look for the SSIS Data Flow Items, see if you can find the OLE DB Destination there. It should be built-in so not missing from that list.

SQL Server Destination only supports local - so you cannot use that destination for a remote SQL Server Instance.
[image]